# Объясните, пожалуйста, код перемещения view

Tags: android, анимация, android-animation

Есть ответ на вопрос, как анимировать `imageView` таким образом, чтобы из любой позиции на экране view перемещалось в центр:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276251/how-to-animate-a-view-with-translate-animation-in-android

Не сильна в java, и не могу разобраться, что происходит в методе `moveViewToScreenCenter` после  `this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );`
и до `anim.setDuration(1000);`

Comment: вычисляются координаты x и y куда будут перемещать view. Ваш, Кэп =)

Comment: ну это и понятно, непонятно каким образом, куча переменных, сложно разобраться. statusBarOffset - это разница между шириной дисплея и шириной контейнера. Далее originalPos - это массив из чисел 0 и 1. Я не понимаю, для чего он нужен. Что за метод getLocationOnScreen( originalPos ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разъяснения к коду, которые вы и просили:

```
private void moveViewToScreenCenter( View view )
{
    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.rootLayout );
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
    int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - root.getMeasuredHeight();// размер экрана - высота rootLayout в пикселах(фактически высота statusBar)

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos ); //позиция на экране view, x  и y записываются в массив originalPos

    int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2; //середина экрана по х
    xDest -= (view.getMeasuredWidth()/2); //вычитаем половину ширины view 
    int yDest = dm.heightPixels/2 - (view.getMeasuredHeight()/2) - statusBarOffset; //середина экрана по у вычитаем половину высоты view и вычитаем высоту statusBar

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );// анимация перемещения view, все параметры - дельты 
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения, кое что уже сама нашла в документации. Просто не могла понять, почему view, в итоге, не попадает центр)). А насчет последнего замечания, так у автора все картинки, вроде бы, смещены вправо от центра, и анимация идет справа налево.

Comment: @VolhaGomel все верно у него указано, я просто не учел, что в параметрах дельта указывается а не абсолютные значения. Поправлю

Comment: Т.е. дельта - это не координаты объекта, а разница между его первоначальным положением и тем, где закончится анимация? В данном случае xDest = по-сути это значение отступа слева (left margin) view, когда он будет находится в центре, а originalPos[0] - значение left margin переданного view. Во втором параметре TranslateAnimation передается дельта, которая представляет собой разницу между значением leftmargin view, если бы он был расположен в центре, и left margin переданного view. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @VolhaGomel все верно поняли =)